# matching regexp with contained keyword in vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, vim

I am using vim, and I want to highlight the following construct (which is accepted in ifort, but rejected by xlf)

```
write(5,*), foo
```

note the comma before the foo variable. I tried the following

```
syn match fortranWriteComma "write\s*\(.?*,.?*\),"
```

This works well as long as instead of "write" I use anything else. Example

```
syn match fortranWriteComma "whatever\s*\(.?*,.?*\),"
```

this matches and correctly highlights

```
whatever(5,*),
```

If I use write, the keyword recognition of write kicks in and does not perform any highlighting. How can I set vim to have the match prevail over the keyword recognition ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's with the comma before the foo?

Comment: @Idigas : technically, it's incorrect. gfortran and ifort however don't complain. xlf goes mad and aborts. The reason why I type it is out of muscle memory when I write `print *,`, so I want an alarm every time I put a comma, otherwise I always break the build with xlf

Comment: `?*` is notpart of the regex syntax in vim. Use `\{−}` for non greedy matching (see `:help /\{-}`). Note that in Perl it is `*?` not `?*`. Here by **pure luck** you match something because you have a character and 0 occurrences of an interrogation mark.

Comment: @StefanoBorini - Ah ok, that makes sense. Not a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved by redefining the keyword as a match

```
syn clear fortranReadWrite 
syn keyword fortranReadWrite backspace close endfile inquire open print read rewind 
syn match fortranWrite "write" contained
hi def link fortranWrite Keyword
syn match fortranWriteComma "write\s*(.*,.*)," contains=fortranWrite
hi def link fortranWriteComma Error
```

Unfortunately, this is still not perfect, as the "write" remains yellow, and only the parenthesized stuff becomes highlighted.

[image]

I could not fix this, but it's ok for my purposes. If anyone has a way of getting write in yellow in normal conditions, but everything red if the comma is added, please add it in comments so I can refine it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q.** If I use write, the keyword recognition of write kicks in and does not perform any highlighting. How can I set vim to have the match prevail over the keyword recognition

**A.** I believe you should be able to have it both ways using a **[*`transparent syntax region`*:](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html#transparent)**

> #### TRANSPARENT
>
> In a C language file you would like to highlight the () text after a "while"
>   differently from the () text after a "for".  In both of these there can be
>   nested () items, which should be highlighted in the same way.  You must make
>   sure the () highlighting stops at the matching ).  This is one way to do this:
>
> ```
> :syntax region cWhile matchgroup=cWhile start=/while\s*(/ end=/)/
>   \ contains=cCondNest
> :syntax region cFor matchgroup=cFor start=/for\s*(/ end=/)/
>   \ contains=cCondNest
> :syntax region cCondNest start=/(/ end=/)/ contained transparent
> ```
>
> Now you can give cWhile and cFor different highlighting.  The cCondNest item
>   can appear in either of them, but take over the highlighting of the item it is
>   contained in.  The "transparent" argument causes this.
>      Notice that the "matchgroup" argument has the same group as the item
>   itself.  Why define it then?  Well, the side effect of using a matchgroup is
>   that contained items are not found in the match with the start item then.
>   This avoids that the cCondNest group matches the ( just after the "while" or
>   "for".  If this would happen, it would span the whole text until the matching
>   ) and the region would continue after it.  Now cCondNest only matches after
>   the match with the start pattern, thus after the first (.